# Why does the URL contain data from the HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, drupal

On one of my pages in Drupal, I have a panel that contains the following html code:

```
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var  dirService, initAddr, endLoc, doc;
       function initialize() {
        dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
         initAddr = "85 E San Fernando Street San Jose, CA 95113";
       }

    function showLocation() {
        doc = document.getElementById("results_area");

        endLoc = document.forms[0].address2.value;
        findFromAddress();
    }


       function findFromAddress() {
         dirService.route({'destination': initAddr, 'origin': endLoc, 'travelMode': google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING}, function (result, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var distance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                var miles = Math.round(distance * 0.000621371192 * 100) / 100;
            alert("Distance from Loves Cupcakes is roughly" + miles
                 + " miles" + "Estimated price is (price)" );
          }
          else {
            alert("INVALID ZIP CODE");
          }
        });
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<p> Enter in zip code of desired delivery location</p>
<form action="#" onsubmit="showLocation(); return false;">
    <p><input class="address_input" name="address2" size="20" type="text"  /> <input name="find" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
<p id="results_area">&nbsp;</p>
```

Simply put, it takes a zipcode and calculates the distance from a specified location.

The HTML page works on its own, but when I enter it into a panel, some weird stuff happens that I don't understand. When I hit the "Submit" button, the page is reloaded, but with a slightly different URL and no alert box pops up. The URL changes from ../contact_us to ../Contact_Us?address2=&find=Search#. I understand the address2 and search are elements from my HTML code, but can anyone help me figure out why this is happening (I am assuming it has something to do with drupal, not the code itself, but not too sure)?

Answer (score 0):

When the submit button is clicked, the browser sends a HTTP GET request to the address with the address2 and find values as parameters.

In your case, address2 has no value and find has a value of 'Search'

See here for a comprehensive explanation : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3